# BHO/Toolbar: prevent Internet Explorer from recording history

Tags: internet-explorer, bho

I've got a fairly elaborate BHO/Toolbar thing in place that has a "login" feature. My goal is to make sure that IE does not record history while toolbar is "logged-in".

I can't just delete history entries, since they might have been added while toolbar was "logged-out".

Is there a mechanism that would notify me when a history entry is about to be added?

**EDIT1:** Related post on social.msdn.com: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/843eea9c-6de7-47b5-aecd-0515ce894cd1/

Thanks,
Yuriy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jeffdav:

No.  What you want to do will not be easy.  The only access to Url History that you get is IUrlHistoryStg (and IUrlHistoryStg2).  Neither interface provides what you want.  I'm fairly certain there is no "onBeforeWriteToHistory" event.  If such an event existed, I would expect it to be in DWebBrowserEvents2.  And you'll see that there is no such event.
Writing to history is really an internal thing for IE.

Comment: Followup: IUrlHistoryStg2::DeleteUrl() doesn't work ... [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774951%28VS.85%29.aspx)